# FB Graph API fails to retrieve profile pic

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

following this doc:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/picture

I have tried this code to get a user profile pic:

```
new Request(session, "me/picture",
                getRequestParameters("type", "large"), HttpMethod.GET,
                new Request.Callback() {

                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                        if (response.getError() == null) {

                            GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();
                            Object a = graphObject.getProperty("data");
                            // .getProperty("url");
                            saveProfilePicInSP("");
                        }
                    }

                    private void saveProfilePicInSP(String profileUrl) {
                        sharedPreferencesProvider.putString(
                                PublicMacros.SP_FB_PROFILE_PIC, profileUrl);

                    }
                }).executeAsync();
```

but the response is:

```
{Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: GraphObject{graphObjectClass=GraphObject, state={"FACEBOOK_NON_JSON_RESULT":"����\u0000\u0010JFIF\u0000\u0001\u0002\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0000��\u00006Photoshop"}}, error: null, isFromCache:false}
```

how can I fix this?

simulating in here:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=me%2Fpicture%3Ftype%3Dlarge&version=v2.1

shows a different response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "url": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xpa1/v/t1.0-1/s200x200/10491996_10154355617635153_5470840249552886594_n.jpg?oh=4dd714d8106d30cd7e548ad3380c7f24&oe=54924987&__gda__=1415264790_4286480e7bd886198a68824ae4f25bf1", 
    "is_silhouette": false
  }
}
```

Comment: Well that response has `JFIF` in it quite at the beginning, so most likely it _is_ actually a JPEG image … (Although it should be longer if it was one, but I don’t know if what you’ve shown us is the full response?) Maybe you are not handling the result correctly here …

Comment: how can i handle this correctly?  simulating in here:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=me%2Fpicture%3Ftype%3Dlarge&version=v2.1

shows a different response:

Comment: When I request `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/me/picture?type=large&redirect=false&access_token=…` using a valid user access token, I get exactly the same response as in Graph API Explorer … And if you want that to deliver the actual image data instead of a JSON structure containing information _about_ the image, then you have to remove `redirect=true` – then this call will result in an HTTP redirect to the actual URL of the image on Facebook’s CDN.

Comment: that solved my problem. `redirect=false`

Comment: OK, added this as an answer with a little extra explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `/…/picture` edge for several object types in Graph API offers two different result “formats”:

- you can either get a JSON structure with some info about the picture (f.e. `is_silhouette`, which will tell you whether it is a user-uploaded image or rather the default image that Facebook uses for the object type if the user did not chose one, and `url` with the URL of the image on their CDN), or
- you can get an HTTP response that issues a redirect to the location of the picture on their CDN – useful f.e. for direct client-side displaying of the picture, or if you want to request and store it from within your app.

The parameter `redirect` allows you to explicitly specify which of those two you want. (The “default” can differ based on the request conditions I think, so it is best to specify it explicitly.)

---

FYI, because it is also useful in some situations: There is also `return_ssl_resources` which allows you to specify whether or not you want URLs returned/redirects issued to point to the HTTPS or HTTP version.